# Select a column by header and ROUND to nearest penny using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need to round to the nearest penny using a macro. I've got the "Round" function via the macro currently set up (see code below) to display a pop up for users to manually select the data to be rounded.

However, I would like to have the macro automatically select the entire data-filled range (only where there is data populated -this will be a different column and different amount of rows long each time) of column titled "FEE RATE" and apply the `ROUND` function: `ROUND(DATA,2)`.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xNum As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "ROUND Formula"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Use Mouse to select entire FEE RATE column, then click on OK", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
Rng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Rng.Value, 2)
Next
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, using Find to find the header (assumed it's in row 1) and then assuming the range is the next cell down all the way down. You might want to work up from the bottom in case you have only one entry.

You can also use Evaluate to avoid a loop, although it's probably of marginal benefit.

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

Set rFind = Rows(1).Find(What:="FEE RATE", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
    Set WorkRng = Range(rFind.Offset(1), rFind.End(xlDown))
    'For Each Rng In WorkRng
    '    Rng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Rng.Value, 2)
    'Next
    WorkRng = Evaluate("IF(" & WorkRng.Address & "="""","""",ROUND(" & WorkRng.Address & ",2))")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not getting this code to work. Is there something I need to tweak on my end? I'm still very new to MACRO writing. Thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate please? It sounds as if "FEE RATE" is perhaps not found. Is it in row 1? Try stepping through the code using F8.

Comment: When I run the code, I get no errors, no breaks. It just seems to do nothing. I've tried stepping through the code using F8-same. No results. No errors.

Comment: So what happens on the If line? If rFind is Nothing then the code will end. Try changing to `Lookat:=xlPart` or check for trailing or leading spaces.

Comment: Okay,  this is working, after changing to     Lookat:=xlPart. Thank you so much.